# how to add maven classpath when submitting hadoop task to a hadoop node

Tags: maven, hadoop, classpath

I have a j2ee project managed by maven, i have a hadoop node in local machine,
I submit my hadoop job with code
               `Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("baseFileLocation", baseFileLocation);
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://localhost:9000");

        conf.set("hadoop.job.user","pin");
        conf.set("mapred.job.tracker","localhost:9001");
                ToolRunner.run(conf,new LDAJob(), ldaArgs);`

but I got some some ClassNotFoundexception after submitting the job. Then I add dependency jars to  $HADOOP_PREFIX/libexec/lib/ , and the job was finally done. 
The dependency jars are all in local maven repository, and maven repository is already in classpath, What should I do if i want hadoop to know the where dependency jars are except adding dependency jars to $HADOOP_PREFIX/libexec/lib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can build a soft links in $HADOOP_PREFIX/libexec/lib/ which point to your maven repository path.

If you use eclipse,you can add the maven repository path to the project build path:

```
window->preferences->java->Build Path->ClassPath Variable
```

create a `M2_REPO` = your repository path